# Sleep in booster seats

Tags: sleep, travel, car-seat

We frequently travel in the car at night, and booster seats aren't comfortable for kids to sleep in.  We've tried pillows on either side of their heads but this doesn't help when they fall asleep and heads slump forward.

Also tried a C-shaped pillow that supports the head on either side, but it has padding behind the neck as well, and this promotes slumping forward, eventually defeating any comfort by the side padding.

I'm looking for any tricks or products which make booster seats comfortable to sleep in, including addressing the slumping-forward problem?

Comment: Some 9-18 kg booster seats can be mounted in the direction opposite to where you're driving and tilted slightly. Go to a shop which has many booster seats and ask an assistant. 18+ kg seats, however, do not have such option (as far as I know).

Comment: Yes, a shame back facing seating isn't more common, it's safer for all .

Comment: How old are the children here?

Comment: 3 thru 7 years, and 40-55 lbs.

Comment: Try turning the C-shaped pillow around? So that there's nothing in the neck. Some pillows don't stay in place like that but some do!

Answer (score 1):

We also have this problem.

It helps a bit if the child seat allows a bit of recline, and if it has an impact shield aka a 'wedge' (instead of a harness) then that means that if the seat is in the upright position then the child can sleep leaning forwards on the shield.

We have this type here:
http://www.kiddy.de/en/car-seats/9months-4years/kiddy-energy-pro.html
and it's all right. Unfortunately the older-child version we have doesn't recline :( although I think they do a different version that does.

Comment: Indeed the 'wedge' is a step in the right direction.  Thinking of a big, furry beach ball they could slump forward on..

Answer (score 1):

We have a neck pillow with no padding at the back, just a length of fabric holding two kidney-shaped pillows together. It worked so well for the toddler I ended up buying a bunch more, so the whole family has their own to use as travel pillows.

I'll post a picture later.

It was made by a local SAHM-business and we got it years ago, but similar things may be available online (perhaps Etsy) and/or if you're crafty, do-it-yourself!

Comment: Yes please post a pic!